# Accordion Menu - One Open Only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some difficulties trying to get my jQuery accordion style menu to only display one open content at a time along with the `active` class only being set on the open menu options without the parent also being toggled.

This should be quite simple, however I appear to be somewhat rusty! I've made a snippet below of my working script which does not follow the rule I want to apply meaning you can expand all menu items to their maximum without any other menu items being collapsed.

I've browsed StackOverflow for answers however none which I have come across have resolved my problems, nevertheless I am certain this will be a duplicate of another question so my apologies in advanced!

```js
$('.SideNav .Menu li a').click(function() {
 if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
 }
});
```

```css
ul.Menu li ul { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SideNav">
  <ul class="Menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:;">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">2 - I have siblings</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">2.1 - I have siblings</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">2.2 - I have siblings</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">3 - I have siblings</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">3.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">3.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### To clarify:

Upon clicking on the menu, all which are not part of the same tree I am wanting to slide back up including those on the same level if another sub-category is clicked on thus meaning if you are on `2 > 2.1 > 2.1.1` and then click on `2 > 2.1 > 2.1.2` then `2 > 2.1 > 2.1.1` will slide back up, click on `2 > 2.2` and all within `2 > 2.1` will slide back up.

Comment: Where is accordion you used?

Comment: @Aravind Isn't this what this style of menu is called?

Comment: what do you exactly want? if you can add screenshot or your menu flow?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @Aravind I'm wanting it so that upon clicking on the menu, all other items which aren't in that tree slide back up so if you're on `2 > 2.1 > 2.1.1` and then click on `2 > 2.1 > 2.1.2` then `2 > 2.1 > 2.1.1` will slide up, same if you clicked on `2 > 2.2` then `2 > 2.1` onwards would all slide up.

Comment: there is one simple trick for that, when ever you receive click on item, first class all items with same class and then open the one on which you got click

Comment: @abhirathore2006 I cannot see this sliding up all items within `2 > 2.1 > 2.1.1` upon clicking on `3`, could you maybe make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this will help.

```js
$('.SideNav .Menu li a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings().find("ul").hide('fast');
 if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
 }
});
```

```css
ul.Menu li ul { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SideNav">
  <ul class="Menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:;">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">2 - I have siblings</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">2.1 - I have siblings</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">2.2 - I have siblings</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">2.2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">3 - I have siblings</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">3.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">3.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is almost perfect! Could you kindly make it so that upon having `2 > 2.1 > 2.1.1` expanded and you click on `3` that not only does `2` slide up but all within `2` so when you reopen they are closed?